# Razor code error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dynamic, razor, webmatrix

I have the following code :

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("WebPageMovies") ;
    var selectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Movies";
    var searchGenre = "";
    var searchTitle = ""; 
    var selectedData = ""; 

    // search by Genre
    if(!Request.QueryString["searchGenre"].IsEmpty() ) {
        selectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Movies WHERE Genre = @0";
        searchGenre = Request.QueryString["searchGenre"];
    }

    // searching by title ( but any word or words that match a title will work). 
    if(!Request.QueryString["searchTitle"].IsEmpty()){ 
        selectCommand += " AND Title LIKE @1"; 
        searchTitle = "%"+ Request.QueryString["searchTitle"] + "%"; 

        }
    // if both textboxes are empty, then the following is dispayed 
    if(searchGenre != null)
    {
           selectedData = db.Query(selectCommand, searchGenre,searchTitle);
    }
           else 
           {
               selectedData = db.Query(selectCommand,searchTitle);

           } 
    var grid = new WebGrid(source: selectedData, defaultSort: "Genre", rowsPerPage:3);

}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>

  <style type="text/css">
  .grid { margin: 4px; border-collapse: collapse; width: 600px; }
  .grid th, .grid td { border: 1px solid #C0C0C0; padding: 5px; }
  .head { background-color: #E8E8E8; font-weight: bold; color: #FFF; }
  .alt { background-color: #E8E8E8; color: #000; }
  </style>     

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Movies</title>
</head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Movies</h1>
        <form method="get">
  <div>
    <label for="searchGenre">Genre to look for:</label>
    <!-- in order for the textbox to rememebr what search value was entered, we need to provide a value attribute with that search value in our HTML-->
    <input type="text" value="@Request.QueryString["searchGenre"]" name="searchGenre" value="" />
    @*<input type="Submit" value="Search Genre" /><br/>*@
    (Leave blank to list all movies.)<br/>
    </div>
    <div>
          <label for="SearchTitle">Movie title contains the following:</label>
          <input type="text" name="searchTitle" value="@Request.QueryString["searchTitle"]" />
          <input type="Submit" value="Search Title" /><br/>
   </div>
</form>
     <div>
   @grid.GetHtml(

    tableStyle: "grid",
    headerStyle: "head",
    alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
    columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("Title"),
        grid.Column("Genre"),
        grid.Column("Year")
    )
)
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Don't worry about the length of it, just focus on the razor code. In brief, I have two textboxes and one button. I would like to display a table when a user puts in a value in either the "Title" or the "Genre" or both the search boxes. However, I am getting the following error:

[image: clickhere]

Comment: I have request, don't put database calling in view. You must layer your application. Here view is doing too many things. It is a design flaw in your application. Distribute some responsibility in controller, model and repository/data layer.

Comment: @Imrul, I am following a tutorial from ASP.NETwebsite. Appreciate your feedback though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You error is related to the type of this variable that happens to be string:

```
var selectedData = "";
```

See that you're trying to assign the query result to it and `db.Query` returns an `IEnumerable<dynamic>`.

```
selectedData = db.Query(selectCommand, searchGenre,searchTitle);
```

Change that variable to:

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> selectedData;
```